# How to avoid overflowing a multiplication of variables?

Tags: java

If I have the following code:

```
long interval = 0;
interval = ((6000 * 60) * 24) * 30;
```

It won't run because I would need to make every literal a Long. So this would work:

```
interval = ((6000L * 60L) * 24L) * 30L;
```

But what if I'm trying to multiply different variables that are in type char? Say I have:

```
char a, b, c, d;
```

And I give each of these chars a number value so I try:

```
interval = a * b * c * d;
```

If this overflows, I can't just put the L because that would call different variables.

```
interval = aL * bL * cL * dL;
```

I have tried converting each of these chars into a long before hand but the product still returns a negative number.

Comment: You don't have to make all of them `long` literals/values, just one well placed.

Comment: And you can always `1L * ...`.

Comment: Since those seem to be time specifications, I suggest you have a look at `TimeUnit`. You code seems to want to do `TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(30L)`...

Comment: @fge I'd upvote this answer.

Comment: What time values would you be using with `char`?

Comment: @flup answer posted! Still not sure that this is what the op wants but it does seem to be it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying the [multiplicative operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17) to its operands,

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

That is, for this case,

> Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to `long`.

So, really, all you need is to have one `long` value at the beginning of the multiplication. You can achieve this in a few ways. [Either use a cast as demonstrated by Eran.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27690807/438154) Or use a `long` literal in the expression

```
char a, b, c, d;
...
interval = 1L * a * b * c * d;
//        (......) result is a long value
```

By *beginning of the multiplication*, I'm referring to the fact that multiplicative operator is left associative. In your example, if the result of the first application of `*` is a `long` value, it will propagate to the next `*`.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to cast (any) one of the variables to long in order for `long` multiplication to take place :

```
interval = (long)a * b * c * d;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
interval = ((6000L * 60L) * 24L) * 30L;
```

This code seems to be calculating the number of milliseconds in 30 days.

Well, then, use what the JDK has to offer:

```
interval = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(30L);
```

[javadoc for `TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html)